# PHP does not return value after too big image upload

Tags: php, file, file-upload, mamp

I have this super simple PHP code, nothing special. It uploads a file and then runs a function to add the filename to the PHP MySQL database. It works on my local MAMP server, but when I upload it to a public web server the image filename is not added into the database, despite the file being perfectly uploaded to the server. The database call is made and works, the error is between getting the image filename in the variable `post_img`, which is generated in, and returned from, the `upload_image` function and adding it to the database function.

What can it be, why wont PHP return the filename on the public server despite a perfect upload? To clarify the problem, the `upload_image` function returns null when images are above something like 2MB, only on the remote server, which means `post_img` becomes an empty string. But the image file is still perfectly uploaded to the server file system.

I also know other people having the same problem on the same server, with their own code.

```php
if (isset($_POST['post-title']) && isset($_POST['post-content'])) {
    $post_title = $_POST['post-title'];
    $post_content = $_POST['post-content'];
    /* Usually contains the image id returned from the fn, 
    but not always, despite no error. Only happens on remote web server, always works with MAMP*/
    $post_img = upload_image() ?? '';
    $post_img_desc = $_POST['cover-description'] ?? '';
    $author_id = $_SESSION['id'];

    // Add post to database
    $post_id = create_blogpost($post_title, $post_content, $author_id, $post_img, $post_img_desc);

    header("Location: ../blog_post.php?id=$post_id&np=true");
}
```

Comment: FYI, the common **default** PHP value is 2 MB for upload_max_filesize

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Large size image is not uploading in server using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38917840/large-size-image-is-not-uploading-in-server-using-php)